# How to write a program with unspecified number of if-else

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a little problem which looks like a “combinatorics” problem.

We know that `1+2+3+…+k = (k^2 + k)/2`; so, let’s take the set of numbers `S = {1,2,3,4,…,(k^2 + k)/2}` and divide this collection into `k` parts:

The `1st` part has `1` element `1`; the `2nd` has `2` elements `2,3`; the `3rd` has `3` elements `4,5,6`; …and so on…; the `kth` having `k` elements `(k^2 – k + 2)/2,…,(k^2 + k)/2`.

Then I have to draw a random integer in `S`, say `i = random.randint(1, (k^2 + k)/2)` and I have to do some operations according to the element that was drawn:

```
if i == 1:
  `something`
   else if 2 <= i <= 3:
     `something else`
     else if 4 <= i <= 6:
       `something else`
         …
         else: # last line when `i` is in the last `kth` part
           `something else`
```

The number `k` I have to use is variable, so I can't actually write the above program, because I don't know a priori where it should stop...
It seems to me that the best would be to define a function:

```
def cases(k):
    i = random.randint(1, (k^2 + k)/2)
    if i == 1:
        `something`
        else if 2 <= i <= 3:
            … and so on…
```

But the problem remains: how could I write such a function without a specific `k`? There may be a trick in Python to do this, but I don't see how.
All ideas will be welcome.

Comment: Is that indentation correct? It looks like the `elif`s would never fire unless you're incrementing `i`.

Comment: You should be using `elif` and they need to be at the same indentation level as `if`.

Comment: Your indenting is highly non-standard.
If your ‘k’ is variable, how do you know what your ‘something else’?  If the code is different in each case, you need a finite amount of cases because you need code for each one.  However, often you can do something table driven.  For exmaple, use floor to get an int, then use a dict of ints to functions you want to run.

Comment: Without knowing how the value maps to the action (what will you do for k-3?), we can't answer this, and -- in general -- it can't be written.

Comment: What is it that you want to do where you have `something`? You would need someway to determine what that `something` is based on the value of `i`. If you give some more details about what that something is then maybe I can suggest something.

Comment: If you need to do something an indefinite number of times, it screams for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the indenting; I acknowledge it's wrong. Following the comment of `Zach Munro`, I allow myself an answer to better clarify the idea that I had in mind and which was not very clear.
Below is the kind of program I was thinking of; the `something` and `something else` are actually similar, for they use the same function, but with a different domain each time:

```
def cases(start, end, k):
    delta = (end - start) / k
    i = random.randint(1, (k**2 + k)/2)
    if i == 1:
        # random in the 1st part
        x = random.uniform(start, start + 1*delta)
    elif 2 <= i <= 3:
        # random in the 2nd part
        x = random.uniform(start + 1*delta, start + 2*delta)
    elif 4 <= i <= 6:
        # random in the 3rd part
        x = random.uniform(start + 2*delta, start + 3*delta)
    ...
    elif (k**2 – k + 2)/2 <= i <= (k**2 + k)/2:
        # random in the kth part
        x = random.uniform(start + (k-1)*delta, start + k*delta)
```

The question is always how to stop using `...` in the program, but to make something that runs when the parameters are provided (`start` is the beginning of an interval, `end` is the end of the interval and `k` is in fact the number of parts into which we separate this interval).

Basically, we sample more and more as we move away from the origin of the interval.